# Suggested tag: datasource for the questions on data sources

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-creation-process

UPDATE

I was adding tag to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200984/where-can-i-find-historical-raw-weather-data` and was unable to find apropriate tag, so marked as `database`.

I'm suggesting here tag: `datasource` for the questions regarding / looking for data sources bacause don't have enough credentials.

Comment: *"questions regarding / looking for data sources."* sounds off topic to me

Comment: Sounds very broad. Please provide some questions where you feel that tag would help clarify and categorize it.

Comment: There already is datasource tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datasource .

Comment: @S.L. Barth When I was cheking it not appeared in the search results.

Comment: That question is off-topic on SO, so why edit it to add a tag?

Answer (score 9):

Every data source is unique. A generic tag for all data sources isn't going to be useful. Once upon a time we had a [programming-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages) tag, and to this day I'm not sure why it ever existed or what it was useful for. I'm not sure how a similar tag for data sources would be any different or a more useful categorization tool.